# How to determine the right number if "(" and ")" for a boolean IF statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

Is this correct? Should it be made more simple somehow? Should there be more `"("` and `")"` on it, is this a safe 'if' statement for all situations?

```
if (empty($depart_raw) || empty($arrival_raw)) {
    return "";
}
```

I ask because I get confused with how to know how many `"("` and `")"` to surround these kind of statements. To be clear, the above is attempting to check to see if either of the two variables are empty then to return a blank for the function.

Comment: its depends on number of checking and grouping of logical operators.

Comment: The problem with questions like that is that all we can answer now is Yes or No. Did you try the code? Did it work? If you lack of confidence to say whether it really does what you want, write a Unit Test

Comment: This is correct and optimal as is. I'd question the use of `empty` though. Read this: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: your code is good, it does what you think it does

Comment: What they said. This particular example is safe, but nothing is safe in "all situations". Some situations are more problematic than others. An answer is impossible.

Comment: @Gordon I tried the above code, yes it works, but I don't have extensive knowledge of PHP yet which is why I asked. I'm looking for a way not to be confused about this in the future from people more experienced than I am about this. If you spend 8 hours a day writing PHP, then you have something worthwhile to share, if you are kind.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the pointer. So from your experience it is better to check for empty and isset?

Comment: @Edward If the variable is **supposed to exist**, *don't* use `isset` or `empty`. Just compare to `== false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if` statement requires one set of parentheses:

```
if (...)
```

Whether any `...` expression within that requires parentheses or not depends on what the expression is. `empty` is a <strike>function</strike> language construct which requires its own set of parentheses as part of the function call:

```
empty($a)
```

Two expressions joined by an operator do not require parentheses; this is just fine:

```
$a || $b
empty($a) || empty($b)
```

If you have multiple operators, you may need to influence their precedence grouping using parentheses, just like in math:

```
(1 + 2) * 3
1 + (2 * 3)
($a || $b) && $c
$a || ($b && $c)
```

Adjust as needed.

Comment: `1 + (2 * 3)` and `$a || ($b && $c)` do not need parentheses :) More about precedence: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: I'm visualizing an example here! :P

Comment: I know, I do use parentheses in that manner for readability.